Why does walletprocesspsbt finalize the psbt but not return the transaction hex?
I am currently using walletprocesspsbt to optionally finalize a psbt and fill in bip32derivs if not signed already. The psbt is fully signed and finalized but I have to make an additional rpc command finalizepsbt to get the hex, is there a reason walletprocesspsbt doesn't return the final tx hex?

My understanding of the documentation is that it should return the hex by default if the transaction is final. Could you clarify that it indeed is complete before you call finalizepsbt but the result of walletprocesspsbt does not contain the hex?

It's walletprocesspsbt which is not returning the hex. I am still on v0.25.0 if that is relevant.

I realize my previous answer is wrong.
BIP174 defines a number of distinct rules, including:

Updater (fill in information about a transaction)
Signer (produce signatures)
Finalizer (construct scriptSig/witnesses using all information/signatures)
Extractor (convert PSBT to a raw transaction that can be submitted to the network)

The walletprocesspsbt RPC implements the Updater, Signer, and optionally Finalizer roles. The finalizepsbt RPC implements the Finalizer, and optionally Extractor roles.
Nothing really prevents walletprocesspsbt from also performing the Extractor role if possible, but that just has not been implemented.

Ah that makes sense, it finalizes but does not extract.
